# I open Chrome version 115 using Selenium version 4.11.0 but it opens and automatically closes on Python 3

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

option=webdriver.ChromeOptions
webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

Explanation:

- when I run this code, my Chrome opens for a few seconds and then it closes automatically without any error.
  Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behavior for Selenium. At the end of the script, the browser will close automatically unless you add code to keep it open.

To keep it open, you could add a `breakpoint()` to the end:

```py
breakpoint()
```

To get out of the breakpoint, type `c` in the console and hit Enter. The script will then finish.

You could also keep the browser window open after the script finishes by detaching the browser from chromedriver. That feature can be set via options:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Comment: I add a break point but it does not work

Comment: Or use: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: what does pdb stands for

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: and where to use pdb.set_trace

Comment: `pdb.set_trace()` opens the Python Debugger with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will work 100 percent

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)
```

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

you don't use this